# Web scrape with slider on page

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to scrape the data from https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Futures-and-Options-Prices/Equity-Index/Hang-Seng-Index-Futures-and-Options?sc_lang=en.  However, I don't know how to take care of the slider so that it will be moved to both ends.

From the source, I guess I may have to find a way to change the left and right style to 0% like

```
<div class="noUi-connect" style="left: 0%; right: 0%;"></div>
```

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the From/To input fields instead, then .sendkeys. Give this a try:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#From
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='mssval']//input[@class='mss_list val valstart']").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='mssval']//input[@class='mss_list val valstart']").send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='mssval']//input[@class='mss_list val valstart']").send_keys(0)

#To
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='mssval']//input[@class='mss_list val valend']").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='mssval']//input[@class='mss_list val valend']").send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='mssval']//input[@class='mss_list val valend']").send_keys(35000)
```

***Notes:***

1. I am assuming you are performing another selenium action after my last line     `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='mssval']//input[@class='mss_list val valend']").send_keys(35000)`. I am saying this because you need to move away from the field for the "35000" input to take effect, and did not want to and any irrelevant code to prove this works.
2. Normally you could use the `.clear()` method on an input field
   instead of `.sendkeys CTRL+A,` then `BACKSPACE`, but in your website's case, they
   auto populate the fields so `clear` didn't do the trick.

Comment: Thankssssssssssssssssssssss

Comment: No prob, just click on the tick next to the answer so you mark it as "Answered"